# What are the different valid prototypes of 'main' function?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function)

What are the different valid prototypes of 'main' function?

Are there some non-standard prototypes also supported only by a few vendors?

Comment: Same as [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function).

Comment: some compilers also support void main()

Answer (score 5):

The C standard (§ 5.1.2.2.1) defines two entry point prototypes:

```
int main(void);
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

Other than that, every OS has its own additional non-standard entry points. WinMain, etc.

Comment: You haven't quite covered it all. Note also that an alternative to `int main(int argc, char **argv);` is `int main(int argc, char * argv[]);`. In both cases you are saying `argv` is an array of elements of type `char *`, or otherwise stated: an array of C-strings.

Comment: Here's some more good documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function.

Answer (score 2):

The full prototype allowed by gcc is:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[], char *envp[])
```

but `envp` is rarely used. Omitting `argc` and `argv` is also considered acceptable.

Comment: `envp` is not specified in C.  C includes the two listed by Alex, but it allows "some other implementation-defined manner", including that one.

Comment: @Matthew: Interestingly, `gcc -pedantic` does not complain about `envp`.

Comment: Of course not. The standard _allows_ implementation-defined additional prototypes, so as long as GCC documents the extra parameter(s), it's standards-conformant.

Comment: true.  I checked, and the specific warning (enabled by -pedantic) is -Wmain.  That says "main should be a function with external linkage, returning int, taking either zero arguments, two, or three arguments of appropriate types."  So it's being a little lax, but that's okay, because of the phrase I mentioned. :)