# Why statement is true when variable are not equal and false when they are equal?

Tags: c

I just started learning C from yesterday and I encountered an issue and I am not getting why it is happening.

The code is this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a=0;
void main() {
    if (a=13) {
        printf("Number Is Equal\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Not Equal\n");
    }
}
```

It should show not equal but it is still showing Number is equal and i tried other numbers too in place of int a; 
If i assign the value of int a=13 and then if i run the statement if(a=13) then it is true but if i do the same with 0 on both place then it shows not equal.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `a = 13` assigns 13 to `a` and the value of the expression is `13`, i.e. not 0. Did you want `==`? Probably a duplicate for this somewhere, although difficult to search when you don't know the terms. (Good compilers will warn you of an assignment within an `if` condition check, don't ignore these warnings.)

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator - you’re assigning 13 to `a`, which evaluates as “true”.  You need to use `==` to compare values - `if ( a == 13 )`

Comment: Is there not a canonical dupe target for this kind of questions? Looks like this has been discussed a million times already...

Comment: I know about comparison operator but in this case i was not doing comparison  bcz in comparison case the code is working as expected but i am not getting this thing that when i do int a=0 and if(a=0) then it fires the else statement that i don't expect and if i write int a=0 and if(a=1 or any number) then it fires if statement.

Comment: @Ayu: Did you not read my first comment? The value of the expression a = 0 is 0, the value of a = 13 is 13. It's this property that allows you to write things like a = b = 13.

Comment: @Bathsheba So are we assigning the new value which means 13 to a?

Comment: @Ayu: Yup. That's the one.

Comment: Okay but if we do a=0 in both place which means int a =0 and if(a=0) then why it is showing not equal? 
Please don't be annoyed or frustrated from my question bcz i am completely new to this.

Comment: @Ayu: Seriously, now is the time for you to read this (and don't forget to purchase a copy) https://www.dipmat.univpm.it/~demeio/public/the_c_programming_language_2.pdf

Comment: @Bathsheba ok I will read it and then I will post in comments if I got any questions

Comment: @Ayu: Once you've read that (and completed the example exercises), you'll be answering questions!

Comment: @Ayu - in a Boolean context, 0 means “false”.  Again, `if (a=0)` *assigns* 0 to `a`, and the result of the expression is the value of `a` after the assignment - it’s the same result as writing `if (0)`, which means the `else` branch gets taken.

Comment: Please note that the K&R book is hopelessly outdated and filled with errors. It is not something I'd recommend anyone to read, least of all newbies.

Comment: Question has problem explained, contains a code snippet showing what OP has tried, code snippet is able to repeat the OP's problem, question with code snippet clearly lead to a solution -> PUT ON HOLD AS OFF-TOPIC. I don't get it...

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning `13` to `a` using the assignment operator, `=`. Use `==` for comparisons.

example:

```
int a=0;
void main()
{
    // Here, a is being checked to see if it is equal to the int 13.
    // a=13 would be assigning 13 to a, and then checking to see if
    // a is "truthy", or, not 0, which is why it was true for you every time.
    if (a == 13) {
        printf("Number Is Equal\n");
    }else{
        printf("Not Equal\n");
    }
}
```

> NOTE: The C Standard specifies that `main()` will return type `int`, (e.g. `int main(){return 0;}`) when in a *hosted environment.* You can deviate from this when you're in a *freestanding environment*, at which point this becomes implementation defined. It is not likely that you are using a freestanding environment. The odds are that you are in a *hosted environment* where your use of type `void` for `main` would violate the C Standard.

Comment: I'm open to down votes with constructive criticism, but this is the correct answer. If I'm mistaken, I'd love to know why!

Comment: `void main()` is not standard C.

Comment: It compiles, runs, it's what OP put into their question, and the solution here addresses the problem OP was experiencing.

Comment: And it sets a bad example. All code snippets presented in answers should be standard C.

Comment: OP never specified if this code is ultimately being compiled for a freestanding or hosted environment. The C standard states that the start up function's name and type are implementation defined for freestanding environments. It's not likely that this is for a freestanding environment, but if I made this change, I'd be making assumptions about OP's  environment.

Comment: Technically, I haven't deviated from the C standard, until OP specifies that they're in a hosted environment. Until they specify that, this shouldn't be an issue. Heck, if I put `int main` in my answer, someone would down vote for changing it, saying "that doesn't match OP! They could be in a freestanding environment!" It sounds like your issue is with the question, and not actually my answer.

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting: Someone who literally just started learning the language the day before is *very likely* (in fact, almost certainly) running on a hosted implementation.  It's best to assume hosted unless otherwise specified.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273507/what-are-the-different-valid-prototypes-of-main-function Yes I know that my favourite C book is full of `void main()` but ain't it about time we moved away from that?

Comment: @Bathsheba No, your favourite book is far worse, it is full of `main()`. Implicit int is not valid C and empty parenthesis is obsolete style since 1990. `void main (void)` however, is a common implementation-defined form, used in pretty much all freestanding systems. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518).

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah sure they were both very smart and talented but that doesn't make the book good per association.

Comment: @JohnBode & @Bathsheba I agree, the OP is not likely to be in a freestanding environment. I could not resist pointing out that this is still technically correct though, since the environment wasn't specified (and the issue for the OP was really about the assignment operator, which the answer does cover). With that said, I have enjoyed the conversation, and I agree that this likely should be `int main()`. I've made an edit pointing this out with an explanation and I hope I have earned your up vote :).

Comment: Yup. Downvote converted to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
int a=0;
if (a=13) { }
```

> It should show not equal ?

**No,** `if` condition always gets true due to the assignment `a=13` which is non zero, you need to use `==` instead.

Change this

```
if (a=13) { } /* = is assignment operator, condition remains always true */
```

to

```
if (a == 13)  {} /* use comparison operator == */
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing `a=13`, which assigns the value 13 to a. Since this is non-zero it is also considered true (zero would translate to false).

You should write `a == 13` instead, using double equal signs, for comparisons.