# How to initialize array elements before using it?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I have to write a program which illustrates the usage of pointers with arrays and functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 4

void print(int rows, int cols, int *matrix);

void main(void)
{
    int a[ROWS*COLS],i;
   for(i=0;i<ROWS*COLS;i++)
   {
        a[i]=i+1;
   }
   print(ROWS,COLS,a);
    getch();
}

void print(int rows, int cols, int *matrix)
{
    int i,j,*p=matrix;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
   {
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
      {
        printf("%3d",*(p+(i*cols)+j));
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

The above program prints a matrix with the rows and columns predefined. I want to modify the program such that the rows and columns are entered by the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void print(int rows, int cols, int *matrix);

void main(void)
{
    int ROWS,COLS,a[ROWS*COLS],i;
   printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
   scanf("%d",ROWS);
   printf("\nEnter the number of columns: ");
   scanf("%d",COLS);
   for(i=0;i<ROWS*COLS;i++)
   {
        a[i]=i+1;
   }
   print(ROWS,COLS,a);
    getch();
}

void print(int rows, int cols, int *matrix)
{
    int i,j,*p=matrix;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
   {
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
      {
        printf("%3d",*(p+(i*cols)+j));
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

This programs is giving an error that the variables ROWS and COLS are being used before they are being declared. How to solve this problem.

Comment: yea kinda... had to write a program using pointers, arrays and functions... was having trouble with the array declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to allocate `a` on the heap:

```
int main(void)
{
   int rows,cols,*a,i;
   printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
   scanf("%d",&rows);
   printf("\nEnter the number of columns: ");
   scanf("%d",&cols);
   a = malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));
   for(i=0;i<rows*cols;i++)
   {
        a[i]=i+1;
   }
   print(rows,cols,a);
   getch();
   free(a);
}
```

Notice also that I've:

1. Added ampersands that were missing from the `scanf()` calls;
2. Changed the return type of `main()` to `int`. See [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function)

As you why your code didn't work:

Traditionally, C required constant expressions for array bounds. When `ROWS` and `COLS` were constants, everything was good with your code. Once you've turned them into variables, `a` became a [variable-length array](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). The problem was that the size of the array is computed at the point where the array is declared, and at that point the values of `ROWS` and `COLS` were not yet known.

In C99, it is possible to fix your code by pushing the declaration of `a` down:

```
int main(void)
{
   int rows,cols,i;
   printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
   scanf("%d",&rows);
   printf("\nEnter the number of columns: ");
   scanf("%d",&cols);
   int a[rows*cols];
   for(i=0;i<rows*cols;i++)
   {
        a[i]=i+1;
   }
   print(rows,cols,a);
   getch();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help... and my compiler was giving an error on the malloc so I had to use `a=(int*)malloc(ROWS*COLS*sizeof(int));`

Comment: @RaedShahid, then most probably you are compiling C code as C++. This isn't a good idea.

Comment: I guess so because I'm using Borland C++

Answer (score 1):

```
   printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
   scanf("%d",&ROWS);
   printf("\nEnter the number of columns: ");
   scanf("%d",&COLS);
```

Comment: i always miss the ampersand :P

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the array after you get `rows` and `cols` - otherwise it's not make sense.

```
int rows,cols;
scanf("%d %d",&rows,&cols);
int a[rows*cols];
```

By the way, `main` should return `int` (0 if the program ends successfully)

Comment: it was still asking for a constant value for rows and cols.

Comment: Which compiler (and flags) do you use?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to dynamically allocate the array - use `malloc`
2. `scanf("%d", &ROWS);` - notice the `&` - `scanf` requires the address.