# C float values conversion

Tags: c

```
int main(){

    int  N, i, j=0;

    float MA, MB, asum=0, bsum=0, y;

    printf("\number of pairs: "); scanf("%d", &N);

    int a[N+1], b[N+1], c[N+1];


    for(i=1; i<N+1; i++){

        printf("\na%d",i); printf("=");
        scanf("%f", &a[i]);


        printf("b%d",i); printf("=");
        scanf("%f", &b[i]);

        printf("\n aSUM= %.6f \n",asum);
        asum+=a[i];
        printf("\n aSUM= %.6f \n",asum);

    }
```

The idea of this code is simple. User inputs int or float values, then they get summed and outputted as a float value. However I'am getting astronomical values straight away. Fe. if it tries to make addition of 0 and 7, it outputs a value of 1088421888.000000. What the heck is going on?? :D

Comment: Remember, if this is `C` and not `C++` your definition of `main()` must be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function for details

Comment: On which operating system, with which compiler, and with which compiler options, are you compiling all this...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sscanf doesn't know about the type of their pointer parameters, so you  read in floats in integer  pointers. Thus, integer pointers  were as  float interpreted.

You  need to scanf into  a  temporary  float variable, and then convert this to integers. So:

```
float  theFloat;
sscanf("%f", &theFloat);
N[a]=theFloat;
```

Comment: O so now if I input 5.6 it gets converted to 5, therefore 0+5.6 becomes 5... I might as well just use ints and get the same result.. I need to input and output values with commas.

Comment: No! You have right! You need to handle the main array as a float array! Your  current code rounds the floats during the integer conversion.

Comment: Thanks! I don't get it why people tend to answer in such a complex way lol. "change {int a[N+1]} to {float a[n+1]}" is all that needed. Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

You should enable all warnings with a modern C compiler (like GCC 4.8).

```
 int a[N+1], b[N+1], c[N+1];
 //...later
     scanf("%f", &a[i]);
```

This cannot work: `%f` is for [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) a control format requiring a `float` pointer, and `&a[i]` is a pointer to an int. (and GCC would have warned about that).

And you have other errors too. Please enable all warnings -e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall`

BTW, it is much better to put `\n` at the *end* of your `printf` format control string (not at the beginning!).

Comment: Ok so how do I input and output float values then? :||

Comment: you don't have *float* values, unless you declare `float a[N+1], b[N+1], c[N+1];`

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong specifier for `int`. It will invoke undefined behavior. You will get anything. You are lucky that you are not getting the desired result!