# Taking pthread id as an input

Tags: c, pthreads

Can we take thread id of pthread as input from the user?
Is this the right way?

```
  int main(int argc, pthread_t id, char *argv[])
```

Or taking the input in a void pointer and then casting it to a long unsigned int? None of this is giving the correct answer. Is there a way that we can do this?

Comment: WTH are you trying to do? What for?

Comment: I want the user to give pthread id as input to another program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The `C` standard specifies two signatures for `main`:

```
int main(void);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Read this for more - [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2108208/1809377). You can pass the `id` of a pthread as a command line argument to `main` and then read it in `argv`. `argv` receives the executable name as the first argument (`./program_name` as below) and then other arguments as supplied. All arguments (delimited by space) are converted to strings literals. Execute your program as

```
./program_name 123454
```

Inside `main`, you would do:

```
// in main

if(argc > 1) {
    pthread_t id = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10)  // converts string to decimal int
    if(id == 0) {
        // either no integer was entered in base 10, or 0 was entered
        // handle it
    }
    // do stuff with id
}
```

Please note that POSIX does not require `pthred_t` to be of integer type. It can even be defined as a structure. You will need to look into your `sys/types.h` header file and see how `pthread_t` is implemented. Then you can print or process it depending on how you see fit.

Include the header file `stdlib.h` for the prototype of `strtol` library function. As the name suggests, it converts a string to `long int` type of given base. Fore more on `strtol`, read this - [man strtol](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

`main` has only two valid prototypes:

```
int main(void);
int main(int, char**);
```

If you wish to pass any arguments to `main` then you have to pass them as strings in the argument vector `argv`.