# Which of the following declarations of function main are standard or standard conforming extensions

Tags: program-entry-point

Which of the following declarations of function main are standard or standard conforming extensions
(Please note that some compilers accept ill-formed main declarations, these should be considered incorrect).

```
A. void main (char* argv[] , int argc )
B. int main () correct
C. void main () 
D. int main (int argc, char* argv [] ) correct
E. int main (int argc, char* argv [], char* arge[] )
```

Comment: C or C++ or something else?  Please add a language tag, as without context this question is meaningless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function) - also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c which contains even more links to other dupes

Comment: I saw the same question. Someone said the right answer is only D