# Program terminated due to "Segmentation fault" (11)

Tags: c

I have to display the numbers in reverse order but i get an error program terminated to "Segmentation fault"(11).

**My code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a,b[100],i;
    printf("Enter the total numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the numbers:\n");
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }
    for(i=a-1;i>=0;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",b[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What debugging and other troubleshooting have you done so far?

Comment: you should also change your `main` signature to [`int main(void)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function/) and check that `a` doesn't exceed the number of elements in `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to replace i++ with i--**

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a,b[100],i;
    printf("Enter the total numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the numbers:\n");
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }
    for(i=a-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        printf("%d\n",b[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Segmentation fault occurs when you are trying to access un-referenced memory or going out of bounds. So as mentioned just change i++ to i-- in second loop.

Comment: Adding a few lines of code always helps. This could be written as a comment instead of a separate answer.