# C: command-line argument as binary not identical to local variable as binary

Tags: c, binary, command-line-arguments, long-long

I have c program that takes in a `long long` argument. When i try to convert this long to its binary representation then it turns out all wrong. But if i set a `long long` variable that is equal to the value of the `long long` argument then i get the correct binary representation.

```
  int main(int argv, long long value)
{
        long long i = value; // value = 2
        long long e = 2;
        printBits(sizeof(e), &e); // 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
        printBits(sizeof(i), &i); // 0000000000000000011111111111110000010000111010101110101000001000
        return 0;
}
```

So as you can see above the argument retrieved through the console as input is no where near to what it should be.

printBits() is a copy paste from this [solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)

Can someone clearify what is happening?

Comment: That's not really how command-line arguments works in C. The second argument to `main` is an *array of strings*.

Comment: What makes you think `value` = 2?  Did you try to print `value` from in your program?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function/

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: .... an *array of **pointer to `char`***.

Comment: @alk  ... If the value of argc is greater than zero, the array members argv[0] through
argv[argc-1] inclusive shall contain pointers to strings,

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting this. It's a perfectly valid question from someone who doesn't understand how command line arguments work in C.

Comment: @Max Probably because just abut any [beginners book or tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should have told the OP about this?

Comment: Thank you Max. I was thinking exactly the same. This might be very trivial to someone who is experienced with C. But for us who has just begun how should we know that the arguments to the main function is apparently a locked case. But this is to be expected of stackoverflow in my experience.

Comment: @alk Ahh, I missed Joachim's comment, i took that you're pointing out my answer, NVM.

Comment: @alk A pointer to pointer to `char`.

Comment: I am actually voting to close this because you're not telling what are the *expected* results, you're just asking "what's happening" (and the answer is undefined behaviour).

Comment: @Max we are not a tutoring site. This shows no research at all. Passing commandline arguments is explained in every beginners' C book.

Comment: I assure you i spend alot of time researching this before posting here. fact is stackoverflow is apparently not the place to be if you are a beginnner.

Answer (score 3):

The signature for main is

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

Unfortunately C compilers can be pretty permissive, so what is likely happening is that your pointer to `char*` is being silently cast to `long long`, resulting in nonsense.

You need to actually parse the argument e.g. using `strtoll`.

Working with C without the `-Wall` compiler flag is asking for trouble. With all warnings enabled you would have found the issue immediately:

```
warning: second argument of ‘main’ should be ‘char **’ [-Wmain]
int main (int argc, long long value)
    ^~~~
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I wasn't aware that the arguments to the main function was a locked case. So I take it i need to convert from string to long long for this to work.

Comment: But why does the gcc compiler not error if what i am doing is not valid?

Comment: Generally C compilers only error if there is no way they can compile the code. There are (rare) cases where casting between different types is perfectly valid, so in this case it gives you the benefit of the doubt and just prints a warning.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `main()` in your code

```
 int main(int argv, long long value)
```

is invalid and wrong for hosted environments. The second argument is supposed to be of type `char **`. By defining the `argc` equivalent as `long long`, you're trying to receive a `char **` type into a `long long` type, which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as they are not compatible types, anyway.

To put it in other words, the supplied command line arguments, are passed as pointer to strings. You need to apply proper conversion to get them back to `long long` or any other compatible type. **[`strtoll()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll)** is just made for that purpose.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §5.1.2.2.1,

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

and, paragraph 2,

> — If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through
>   `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
>   implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The
>   intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup
>   from elsewhere in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of
>   supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation
>   shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.
>
> — If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by argv[0]
>   represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
>   program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is
>   greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]`
>   represent the program parameters.

Comment: @ScottHunter "some" freestanding environment.