# "Invalid argument" when creating a file

Tags: c, file

Could you help me with the creation of a text file as right now the *fp pointer to the file is returning NULL to the function fopen ?

Using the library `errno.h` and `extern int errno` I get "Value of errno: 22".

`if (!fp)perror("fopen")` gives me "Error opening file: Invalid argument".

In my main function I enter the name of the file:

```
void main()
{
    float **x;
    int i,j;
    int l,c;
    char name_file[30];
    FILE *res;

    /* some lines omitted */

    printf("\nEnter the name of the file =>"); 
    fflush (stdin);
    fgets(name_file,30,stdin);
    printf("Name of file : %s", name_file);

    res=creation(name_file,l,c,x);
    printf("\nThe created file\n");
    readfile(res,name_file);
}
```

The function to create the text file:

```
FILE *creation(char *f_name,int l, int c, float **a) // l rows - c colums - a array 
{   FILE *fp;
    int i,j;

    fp = fopen(f_name,"wt+"); // create for writing and reading

    fflush(stdin);

/* The pointer to the file is NULL: */

    if (!fp)perror("fopen"); // it's returning Invalid argument
    printf("%d\n",fp); //0 ??

    if(fp==NULL) { printf("File could not be created!\n"); exit(1); }

    fflush(stdin);
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
  {
     for(j=0;j<c;j++)
     {
        fprintf(fp,"%3.2f",a[i][j]); // enter every score of the array in the text file
     }
     fprintf(fp,"\n");
  }

    return fp;
}
```

Function to read the file and check if it is correct:

```
**void readfile(FILE *fp,char *f_name)**
{
  float a;
  rewind(fp);
  if(fp==NULL) { printf("File %s could not open\n",f_name); exit(1); }
  while(fscanf(fp,"%3.2f",&a)!= EOF)
    printf("\n%3.2f",a);
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sadly there are several sins in your code. At this point I'd like to encourage you to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If `fopen` returns `NULL`, it's most likely because the file doesn't exist or you don't have reading permissions on the file. `errno` is set in this case, use it.

Comment: Unless the file name is too long, you've got a newline at the end of it.  That is not going to lead to happiness.  Remove the newline returned by `fgets()`.  On Unix-like systems, newlines are allowed in file names, but Windows may prevent such names being created. Also, `t` is not allowed (officially) in `fopen()` open modes on Unix-like systems.  That's a Windows-ism.  You can specify `b` in the open mode; that means 'binary', but it is a no-op on Unix (it matters on Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few wrong things your code.

1.
The correct signatures of `main` are

- `int main(void);`
- `int main(int argc, char **argv)`
- `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

See [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function)

2.
The behaviour of `fflush(stdin)` is undefined. See [Using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979217/1480131).
`fflush` works with **output** buffers, it tells the OS that is should write
the buffered content. `stdin` is an **input** buffer, flushing makes no sense.

3.
Use `fgets` like this:

```
char name_file[30];
fgets(name_file, sizeof name_file, stdin);
```

It's more robust using `sizeof name_file` because this will give you always
the correct size. If you later change the declaration of `name_file` to
an `char` array with less than 30 spaces, but forget to change the size parameter in `fgets`, you
might end up with a buffer overflow.

4.
You are passing to `creation` the uninitialized pointer `p` that is pointing
to nowhere. In said function you cannot read nor write with the pointer `a`.
You need to allocate memory prior to the call of `creation`. At least judging
from the code you posted.

5.
`fgets` preserves the newline (`'\n'`) character, so
`name_file` is containing the newline character. I really don't know if newline
is allowed in file names. I did a google search but found conflicting answers.
I don't think that you want to have newlines in your file names, anyway. It's
best to remove it before passing it to `fopen` (which might be the reason for
the error 22):

```
char name_file[30];
fgets(name_file, sizeof name_file, stdin);
int len = strlen(name_file);
if(name_file[len - 1] == '\n')
    name_file[len - 1] = 0;
```