# reallocing array of structs

Tags: c, realloc

so I have spent some hours trying to figure out why my realloc doesnt enlarge my array of structs, but I seem to make no progress. Realloc either fails or doesnt enlarge the array. Is there any obvious mistake that Im making?

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct fileInfo {
    char accessRights[12];
    short hardLinks;
    short userName;
    short groupName;
    long size;
    char *time;
    char *fileName;
    short nrOfNode;
} fileInfo;


void enlargeFileInfos(fileInfo *fileInfoArray, int currentSize)
{
    fileInfo *temp = (fileInfo*)realloc(fileInfoArray, (currentSize + 1) * sizeof(fileInfo));
    if (!temp) {
        printf("realloc --FAILED--\n");
        return;
    }
    fileInfoArray = temp;
    printf("fileInfo grew to %d item(s)\n", currentSize + 1);
}

int main( )
{
    size_t nrOfDirs = 1;
    fileInfo *fileInfoArr = malloc(sizeof(fileInfo));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        enlargeFileInfos(fileInfoArr, nrOfDirs);
        nrOfDirs++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: `void f(int i) {i=6;} int main() {int x=12; f(x); printf("%d\n", x);}` <-- what does this print?

Comment: What makes you think `realloc()` does not enlarge the array (or at least return a pointer to a larger array)?

Comment: You are passing the pointer by value to enlargeFileInfos, main() never receives the new realloc'ed pointer. Either pass &fileInfoArray as fileInfo** (chaging the function declaration), or make the function return the new pointer.

Comment: well, if I run the script, this is the output I get:
fileInfo grew to 2 item(s)
fileInfo grew to 3 item(s)
realloc --FAILED--
realloc --FAILED--
realloc --FAILED--

Comment: I have tried, what @FBergo suggested, but with no luck. You can find the adjusted code here: [link](https://pastebin.com/ejDXdTx4)

Comment: You used `fileInfoArray` instead of `*fileInfoArray` in the realloc call, the correct line is `fileInfo *temp = (fileInfo*)realloc(*fileInfoArray, (currentSize + 1) * sizeof(fileInfo));`

Comment: @vanderer with the change above it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `realloc` memory on which `fileInfoArray` points to inside `enlargeFileInfos`, you have to pass its address to the function:

```
void enlargeFileInfos(fileInfo **fileInfoArray, int currentSize)
{
    fileInfo *temp = realloc(*fileInfoArray, (currentSize + 1) * sizeof(fileInfo));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("realloc --FAILED--\n");
        return;
    }
    *fileInfoArray = temp;
    printf("fileInfo grew to %d item(s)\n", currentSize + 1);
}
```

Then you call the function in this way:

```
enlargeFileInfos(&fileInfoArr, nrOfDirs);
```

---

As pointed by *Jonathan Leffler* in comments, an alternative way is to return the `realloc`ed memory from the function `enlargeFileInfos`:

```
fileInfo *enlargeFileInfos(fileInfo *fileInfoArray, int currentSize)
{
    fileInfo *temp = realloc(fileInfoArray, (currentSize + 1) * sizeof(fileInfo));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("realloc --FAILED--\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("fileInfo grew to %d item(s)\n", currentSize + 1);
    return temp;
}
```

And than, you use it this way:

```
fileInfoArr = enlargeFileInfos(fileInfoArr, nrOfDirs);
if (fileInfoArr == NULL) {
    /* Handle allocation failure */    
}
```

And after you finish working with `fileInfoArr`, don't forget to free it:

```
free(fileInfoArr);
```

---

I have removed the cast from `realloc`, so take a look on [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), and change the signature of `main` to  [`int main(void)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function/) .

Comment: The alternative is: `fileInfo *enlargeFileInfos(fileInfo *fileInfoArray, int currentSize) { …; return fileInfoArray; }` called like: `fileInfo *newInfo = enlargeFileInfos(fileInfoArr, nrOfDirs); if (newInfo != NULL) fileInfoArr = newInfo;` — taking an ordinary pointer and returning it (returning NULL if the allocation fails).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thanks for the note, I will mention it in my post.

Comment: YW.  Check it carefully — it hasn't been near a compiler and could easily have typos in it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok got it :).