# to remove repeated consecutive characters from a string using c

Tags: c

I have been trying to remove the repeated consecutive characters from a string using c language for an assignment.

The input is like: `sheeeiiisccommminng`

The output must be like: `sheiscoming`

But I am getting the output: `sheiscomng`

I am not able to find out what went wrong here, please give your valuable insights.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char str[100];
    int i, j, k, len;
    printf("Enter any string: ");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    len = strlen(str);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        j = i + 1;
        k = i + 2;
        while (j < len) {
            if (str[j] == str[i]) {
                j++;
            } else {
                str[k] = str[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        len = k;
    }
    printf("\nString after removing characters:"); 
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update the length of the string with `len = k;` **after** the end of the `for` loop.

Note however that you should also set a null terminator at the new length when you shorten the string to make it a proper C string.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    int i, j;

    printf("Enter any string: ");
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        for (i = j = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (j == 0 || str[j - 1] != str[i]) {
                str[j] = str[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        str[j] = '\0';
        printf("String after removing characters: %s\n", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Single loop. Nice one.

Comment: Thank you so much it was very useful @ chqrlie

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your code but you could do something like

```
char str[]="sheeeeisssscommmiingg";
int i, j;
for(i=j=0; str[j]; i++)
{
    str[i]=str[j];
    for(j++; str[j]==str[i]; ++j);
}
str[i]=`\0`;
printf("\n%s", str);
```

After examining a character in the string via the outer loop, subsequent characters which are the same are skipped using the inner `for` loop.

The original string is overwritten.

At the end, the nul terminator is added to the end of the new string.

Also consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function).

Output in this case is:

```
sheiscoming
```