# segmentation fault (core dumped) in c. char** argv[]

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C program in linux. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", *argv[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

`gcc` keeps giving me the error `segmentation fault (core dumped)`
I'm assuming I have to deference `*argv[i]` but I don't know. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

`char** argv[]` should be [`char** argv` or `char *argv[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function/). Then you can do:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
   printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

(**Edit:** Thx for your comments, my C is really a bit rusty.)

Comment: Except `*argv[i]` is just a first letter which is a small number and dereferencing it as a "string" (which is `%s` specifier) will result in segmentation fault again. Should be just `argv[i]`.

Comment: It's just `argv[i]`