# Why does this give a (non zero) error code on termination?

Tags: c, return-value, program-entry-point

This code runs, even produces the expected output. However, in the build log, I always get `Process terminated with status 2 (0 minute(s), 5 second(s))` or some variation of this log.

Code -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main() {

printf("Please enter a character");
char ch = getch();

ch++;
printf("\n%c", ch);


}
```

Sample output (the input was 'a' without quotes)-

```
Please enter a character
b
```

Comment: Why'd you use `void main()`? use `int main()` , unless explicitly mentioned something else by your compiler documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function)

Comment: If the message is output in the _build log_, then it is related the _build_ not the _execution_ of this code.  Did you really mean "_build log_"?  Does your build also _execute_ the code?  That would explain your description, but is unusual and deserves explanation.  Either way, if you are in any way relying on or testing the exit value of a program, you should probably explicitly return a value - otherwise why are you testing it?

Answer (score 1):

If you declare `main` as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, then the current C standard says that reaching the `}` that terminates `main` returns a value of 0. This also holds if `main` is declared with a return type compatible with `int` but with parameters defined by the C implementation.

If you declare `main` differently, as with `void main()`, the C standard does not say what the behavior is, and it is up to your C implementation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd recommend to check [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2108192/2173917).

For a hosted environment, `void` is not a valid return type for `main()`.

That being said, as per this function signature, the return type is `void`, that indicates the call to `main()` returns nothing to the caller (environment). Now, from the environment, try to access the returned value [i.e., the prompt you are getting] would be indeterminate, at best. C standard does not define any behavior for that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you declared `main` without a valid signature (i.e. you gave it the return type `void`), you cannot assume anything about the value that is actually returned to the operating system. If you're compiling for the x86 architecture, then here's what's *probably* happening to explain the returned value of `2`:

```
main:
    ...
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    ; return value from printf is in EAX register
    ret
```

`printf` returns the number of characters written to standard output, 2 in your case with the format string `\n%c`. The return value from `printf` is still in the register designated for holding return values (`EAX`) when you exit from `main`, so that's what `main` returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't return anything from main, any value may get returned. In your case, your program returns `2` as indicated in the message (`status 2`). You need to return `0` to notify other programs that your program run successfully.

```
int main() {
   ....
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C standard says that, if the return type of `main` is compatible with `int` and control reaches the `}` that terminates `main`, then zero is returned. This is a special specification for `main`, different from other functions.

Comment: To complete what @EricPostpischil said, the `return 0;` in the end is anyway implicit for `main()`.