# Polyspace alerts for not forward declaring main()

Tags: c, static-analysis, misra

I have a bunch of executables written in C that are statically analyzed with Polyspace Code Prover and Bug Finder. Both tools flag my `main()` functions for violation of MISRA's Guideline 8.4, with the following message:

*"A compatible declaration shall be visible when an object or function with external linkage is defined.
Function 'main' has no visible compatible prototype at definition."*

Forward declaring `main()` seems to solve it, but that is very "weird" for me and it introduces problems when documenting the project with Doxygen.

Here's the function:

```
int main(int argument_counter, char const *arg_vector[])
```

also as you can see, we couldn't use the traditional `argc` and `argv[]` parameter names because they were too similar to some variables it found on the external headers, which is also superweird in my opinion.

Is this a code problem or is there something wrong with the tools configuration?

Comment: Does the tool still complain if you remove the `const` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function)?

Comment: @Mat sorry for the delay in the response. Yes, my definition is now `SI_32 main(SI_32 argument_counter, CHAR_8 *arg_vector[])` and still get the alert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You often get these kind of false positives from static analysers regarding `main`, when you use an implementation-defined form. But notably, a strictly conforming hosted program shall use this form:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

The name of the parameters doesn't matter, but their types do. `char* []` is not the same type as `const char* []`. The `const` in your code doesn't mark the actual character arrays as `const`, but rather the array of pointers to them. Which is a bit weird, I don't really see why anyone would attempt to overwrite those.

Also notable, `argc` and `argv` *must* be writable in a strictly conforming program, C17 5.1.2.2.1 §2:

> The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall
>   be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
>   startup and program termination

So you should ideally just change the types to be the ones required by a strictly conforming program.

However, many C programs are not strictly conforming hosted programs, so the static analyser must be able to swallow implementation-defined forms of `main` too. There's really no harm in forward declaring `main` either - and you are safe to assume that the compiler does not do so (C17 5.1.2.2.1 §1 "The implementation declares no
prototype for this function.").

Suppose you have the implementation-defined form `void main (void)`. To silence the tool you can simply write:

```
void main (void);
void main (void)
{ ...
```

I strongly suspect the reason for the tool warning is that it's too blunt to recognize that `main` is a special case. Similarly you can get warnings for using `int` as return value from `main`, instead of `int32_t` - which is a false positive, as MISRA-C has an explicit exception for the return type of `main`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It seems reasonable then to forward declare our `main()`, I had never seen it done so it seemed weird at first.

Comment: @JorgeJuanTorresQuiroga It _is_ weird and shouldn't be needed for normal use. Only very special-purpose applications should need it: things like "C runtime" or bootloaders etc that are executed at startup and then call main().

Answer (score 2):

`main()` is an exception to many rules, both within MISRA and without...

For the avoidance of doubt, [MISRA C:2012 Technical Corrigendum 1](https://misra.org.uk/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=-BRmxs8omoM%3D&tabid=57) adds an explicit exception to Rule 8.4 for `main()`:

> The function main need not have a separate declaration.

Comment: We have justified the violation for now, but if the standard itself acknowledges the exception then I think there should be some kind of configuration option in the tool. I will speak with the department that manages this, thank you!