# C Incompatible pointer type message appears to list identical pointer types for expected and actual

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, compiler-errors

I am attempting to write code to dynamically allocate memory for an array of structures. I want to pass the pointer associated with the heap memory space to another function for further use. The following code sample is a rough example of what I want to do (cut down for brevity):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <time.h>

struct password_struct;
void create_password(char password_seeds[], struct password_struct* user_passwords);

void main() {


    char password_seeds[100];
    int num_passwords = 5;
    struct password_struct {
        char password[17];
        char hash[65];
        int entropy;
    };


    struct password_struct *user_passwords = malloc(num_passwords * sizeof(struct password_struct));

    create_password(password_seeds, user_passwords);
    free(user_passwords);
}


void create_password(char password_seeds[], struct password_struct* user_passwords){

}
```

When I attempt to compile this, I get the following error:

```
In function ‘main’:
     c:24:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘create_password’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     create_password(password_seeds, user_passwords);
     ^
     c:8:6: note: expected ‘struct password_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘struct password_struct *’
     void create_password(char password_seeds[], struct password_struct* user_passwords);
          ^
```

The would appear to list the same pointer types for the actual and expected pointer types. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you define the struct inside `main()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because, the definition of the structure `password_struct` in inside `main()`, and not visible outside the scope.

Move the structure definition in file scope (outside `main()` or any other function).

That said, see this one: [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2108192/2173917)

Answer (score 0):

You have two different `struct password_struct` types -- one defined at the global scope and a second defined as local to main.  Despite them having the same name, they end up being two unrelated types, due to being in different scopes.  The function is declared as taking a pointer to the global one, but within main you use a pointer to the local one.

Answer (score -1):

`struct password_struct *user_passwords = malloc(num_passwords * sizeof(struct password_struct));`

Here you are creating memory for password_struct malloc function returns the generic pointer, so type conversion is important so you can convert the generic pointer to password_Struct. So try this

`struct password_struct *user_passwords = (struct password_struct*)malloc(num_passwords * sizeof(struct password_struct));`

This line can resolve your problem.

Comment: Never cast the result of malloc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3742943