# How do I generate random numbers but not repeating and within a certain range based on user input?

Tags: c, arrays, random

Currently, I am experimenting some codes regarding/about random numbers. The problem is, when I run the program, input any number (ex. 12), I, sometimes get the correct and sometimes wrong answer. The correct answer must be any non repeating random numbers based on user input. (ex. input 5, output must be 1. seats[12]=1, 2. seats[19]=1,..., 5. seats[47]=1). I do not know what to do and yeah help me coders!

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
main()
{
    int x,y,chc1A,seats[50]={};
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&chc1A);
    srand(NULL);
    for(x=0;x<chc1A;x++)
    {
        if(seats[rand()%50]==0)
            seats[rand()%50]=1;
        else
            x--;
    }
    for(x=0,y=1;x<50;x++)
        if(seats[x]==1)
        {
            printf("%d. seats[%d] = %d\n",y,x,seats[x]);
            y++;
        }
    getch();
}
```

I do not really know what's wrong please enlighten me.

I run and coded this on Dev C++

What I want to do is: generate random numbers between 0-49 and putting it in an array `seats[50]`. (ex 38 then put 1 in array `seats[38]`). Btw this code represents passengers sitting on a bus with 50 seats. So the "1" means that the seat is occupied.

Comment: The correct answer must be any non repeating random numbers based on user input. (ex. input 5, output must be 1. seats[12]=1, 2. seats[19]=1,..., 5. seats[47]=1)

Comment: Can you add a bit more context? Is zero a random number that you accept?

Comment: The random number I accept is 1 @J...S

Comment: @user3121023 uhm is it necessary to shuffle the array??

Comment: Can you tell us, step by step, how you are trying to solve the problem in the program that you posted?

Comment: @J...S uhh the code that I have posted was about uhh generating random numbers between 0-49 and putting it in an array seats[]. (ex 38 then put 1 in array seats[38]). Btw this code represents passengers sitting on a bus with 50 seats. So the "1" means that the seat is occupied.

Comment: @user3121023 ohh I get it what you are trying to say. Wait lemme try it

Comment: @user3121023 I tried it but it makes my code longer

Comment: Please edit your question to add details and crucial information, don't put them in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part may cause problem.

```
for(x=0;x<chc1A;x++)
{
    if(seats[rand()%50]==0)
        seats[rand()%50]=1;
    else
        x--;
}
```

I think by

```
    if(seats[rand()%50]==0)
        seats[rand()%50]=1;
```

you meant to generate a random number, use that as index to `seats` and if `seats[random_no]` is `0`, set `seats[random_no]` to `1`.

But the random number in the `if` statement and the one in its body are *different* numbers.

You could use

```
    int index = rand()%50;
    if(seats[index]==0)
        seats[index]=1;
```

---

Consider changing the signature of your `main()` function. See [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function)

---

conio.h is not part of the standard, try to avoid its usage. Same goes for `getch()` as it's from conio.h.

---

`srand()` expects an `unsigned int` as argument and `NULL` is not of that type. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand).

Include `stdlib.h` to use `srand()`.

---

And checking the return value of `scanf()` is a good idea. You can see if it failed or not.

Comment: Ohhh okk lemme try it! Also thanks for this detailed answer