# Runtime errors vs memory leak vs linkedit error

Tags: c

My teacher gave us a piece of code as homework and asked us what is the kind of error.

I don't really know what errors exist so that's why I'm asking here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m, n;
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
    int i, ** a;
    a = (int**)malloc(m * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }
    free(a[0]);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

It is either a runtime error, a memory leak, or a linkedit error.

Can anybody help me classify this error and also help me understand the difference between these types of errors?

Thanks.

Comment: To begin with you're not checking the return value from `scanf()` so you have no idea what's actually in `m` and `n` when you try to allocate your multiple one-dimensional arrays.  You can easily get a run-time error from that.  And then, to not have a memory leak, every `malloc()` call needs a corresponding `free()` call (as a first-order comment...).

Comment: So what error is that?

Comment: to use `malloc` and `free`, you need to include `stdlib.h`

Comment: Hint: look what you allocate vs. what you free. Are you sure all memory allocated is eventually freed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a memory leak for any `m > 1`. To avoid it you need to free all "malloced" memory.

In your code first is allocated space for `m` pointers to int. Then it allocates `m` memory blocks having the size of `n` integers.

You free only 2 memory blocks. The second return frees the memory where pointers to allocated blocks are kept. Access to them is lost and this memory cannot be accessed to freed anymore - thus "memory leak"

BTW if it is the code given by the teacher then it shows that he needs to start to read SO to learn some stuff about the C language (or even better read an up to date book about this language).

1. `main` [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function)
2. he should check the return value of `scanf`. He should check if the scanned values make any sense.
3. He should use the correct type for sizes and indexes it is `size_t`
4. He should not cast the result of malloc
5. He should use objects instead of types in `sizeof`
6. He does not include `stdlib.h` required to use `malloc` & `free`.

Quite a lot issues in the 10 lines C programm.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. ^the code was intentionally written with errors by my teacher, by the way. The homework was to decide which errors will happen.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu put all the errors from this answer in your homework you'll get an A+ mark.

Comment: It was like an extra homework, it won't be marked. I just wanted to learn more :)