# Id returned 1 exit status in C and I can't find my mistake

Tags: c, initialization, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>

int wednesday(){
  int discount;
  printf("You are lucky on Wednesdays! You can get discount!\n");
  printf("Is today wednesday? Yes = 1  No= 2\n");
  scanf("%d", &discount);
  return discount;
}

void cost(int wednesday){
  int price;
  int discount;
  if(discount == 1){
    price = price - 2;
  }
  else{
    price = price;
  }
}

void main(){
  int discount;
    
  welcome();
  discount = wednesday();
  cost(discount);
}
```

I write other codes too but this part didn't work I couldn't find my mistake. I would be really happy if you help me to find my mistake.

Comment: backticks are for inline code, you want to format a whole block. Brackets, parenthesis, and semicolons are all part of the source too.

Comment: Post the full error message

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read your error message from top to bottom. There must be some compilation error shown before the message you mentioned.

Comment: Please learn how to format questions properly. It's easy and it will take you only a few minutes of your time.

Comment: In function `cost()` you are reading from uninitialised variables. But the function doesn't *do* anything anyway.

Comment: There is no function `welcome()`

Comment: `discount` and `price` are never initialized. Local variables in C are not initialized to zero by default, they contain an undetermined value.

Comment: The error message `Id returned 1 exit` is probably because there is no `welcome` function in your program. Anyway read the other comments, they are all relevant

Answer (score 1):

In `main` you try to call a `welcome` function that doesn't exist:

```
welcome();
```

Either remove `welcome();` or define the function somewhere above.  That will fix your linker problem, but your code has several other problems:

```
int discount;
if(discount == 1){
```

is problematic.  `discount` is unintialized, so it has an indeterminant value.  I think what you want is

```
if(wednesday == 1){
```

This is the value returned from `wednesday` that you pass to `cost`.

Furthermore, `price` is uninitialized as well, so

```
price = price - 2;
```

results in an indeterminant value.  You should initialize `price` to some initial value.

```
int price = 0; // probably not zero, but whatever the initial price should be
```

Finally, remove

```
else{
  price = price;
}
```

This is a no-op, nothing is gained by setting `price` equal to itself.

You also have an invalid signature for `main`, see [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function)

Comment: You forgot to mention the missing `welcome()` function which is most likely his primary problem.

Comment: @Jabberwocky wow sure did

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is neither declaration of the function `welcome` that is called in `main`

```
welcome();
```

Within the function `wednesday` you need to check whether this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%d", &discount);
```

was successful. To make the function correct you should at least initially initialize the variable discount for example like

```
int discount = 2;
```

In this case if the call of `scanf` will not be successful the function will return the value `2` by default.

Within the function `cost` there are used two uninitialized variables `price` and `discount`

```
void cost(int wednesday){
  int price;
  int discount;
  if(discount == 1){
    price = price - 2;
  }
  else{
    price = price;
  }
}
```

So the function invokes undefined behavior.

Moreover the parameter `wednesday` is not used.

You should declare the function with one more parameter that specifies the price. And the result price should be returned from the function to `main`. For example

```
int cost( int price, int discount ){
  if(discount == 1 && price > 2 ){
    price = price - 2;
  }

  return price;
}
```

Also the variable price should have at least unsigned integer type or maybe a float type.

```
unsigned int cost( unsigned int price, int discount ){
  if(discount == 1 && price > 2 ){
    price = price - 2;
  }

  return price;
}
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```