# How to display and add all even numbers?

Tags: c

How can I display and add all even numbers? The current code displays numbers between 2 numbers in an ascending manner.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int a;
  int b;

  printf("Enter integer a:");
  scanf("%d", &a);

  printf("Enter integer b:");
  scanf("%d", &b);

 if(b > a)
  {
      do {
        printf("Result: %d\n", b);
        b--;
      } while (a <= b);
  }
  else
  {
      do {
        printf("Result: %d\n", a);
        a--;
      } while (a >= b);
  }
  
  }
```

Comment: Use a [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: Depending on whether you want to include '0' as 'even' or not, `if (!a%2)` should work.

Comment: Please, [`main()` -> `int main(void)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function).

Answer (score 2):

To check if an integer is **even** you can check if the [least significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) is **zero**.

To check if an integer is **odd** you can check if the [least significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) is **one**.

You can do that using bitwise AND (`&`).

Something like:

```
if(b > a)
{
    if (b & 1) b--;  // Make b even
    if (a & 1) a++;  // Make a even
    int sum = 0;
    do 
    {
        sum += b;
        printf("b is %d, sum is %d\n", b, sum);
        b = b - 2;
      } while (b >= a);
  }
```

Comment: ok ok I'm done editing :p

Comment: @Cid Nice edit but we just edited at the same time :-)

Comment: my problem right now is how to display the the first output (the first part of the code) and even numbers

Comment: For "old" programmers like us, `a & 1`, immediately says "odd number", but I think `(a % 2) != 0` is clearer and any modern compiler will most likely recognize the case and generate the same code. Personally, I am going away from many of these tricks to nudge the compiler since the compiler will likely do the optimization and I can just focus on clarity. I have to admit, though, that a part of me loves the old tricks :-)

Comment: @Monsterbeginner I don't understand the follow up question in your comment

Comment: @nielsen `For "old" programmers like us, ....` hmm... Do we know each other? Your nick seems very familiar ;-)

Comment: @4386427 Haha, probably not, I was making a bold assumption, sorry if I stepped on a young toe :-)

Answer (score 1):

All even numbers are divisible by 2. You need to check if the remainder of division by 2 is equal to zero. In order to do it, you can use the modulo operator (`%`).
To display only even numbers:

```
if ((b%2) == 0) {
  printf("Result: %d\n", b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a function which I could test for different possible combinations of the extremes:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void evens(int a, int b)
{
    // Make sure to always start from the greatest value.
    if ( a > b ) {
        int tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }

    // Make sure to always start from an EVEN value.
    if ( b % 2 != 0 ) { 
        --b; 
    }

    int sum = 0;
    while ( a <= b ) {
        printf("%d ", b);
        sum += b;
        b -= 2;    // Jump directly to the previous even number.
    }
    printf("\nSum: %d\n", sum);
}

int main(void)
{
    // Those should all print "10 8 6 4 2 \nSum: 30\n"  
    evens(1, 10);
    evens(10, 1);
    evens(2, 11);
    evens(11, 1);
    evens(2, 10);
}
```