# How to pass the pointer of a head to a function in c

Tags: c, linked-list

First of all I'm new to C language and recently started learning. The following code has been developed with my current knowledge.
I was asked to develop a menu driven program involving linked lists to get details from the user and to print and search them using functions. Further, i was advised to create the pointer of the head pointer as a local variable. The problem I'm having is, it gives a runtime error when i try to print or search the data that are entered by the user. And I can't figure out where I have coded wrong. If someone can help me to fix this problem it would be really appreciated.

The code that I've developed so far is ,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node {
    
    int number;
    char name;
    int salary;
    
    struct node*next;
};

    int op,num,i=0,j;
    struct node*temp;
    
//creating the list     
struct node* createlist(){
    
    printf("\nEnter the number of employees : ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    
    struct node*head;
    
    for(j=0;j<num;j++){
    
    if(i==0){
        head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp=head;
    }
    else{
        temp->next=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
        temp=temp->next;
        temp->next=NULL;
    }
    printf("\nEnter the employee number      : ");
    scanf("%d",&temp->number);
    
    printf("Enter the name           : ");
    scanf("%s",&temp->name);
    
    printf("Enter the salary         : ");
    scanf("%d",&temp->salary);
    printf("\n");
    
    
}

return head;
    
}


//printing the list 
void printlist(struct node*head)
{
    
    
    if(temp==NULL){
        printf("\n\nENTER THE DATA BEFORE PRINT!!!!\n\n");
        
    }
    
    else{
        
        temp=head;
        while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\n",temp->number,temp->name,temp->salary);
        temp=temp->next; }
    }
    

}


void searchemp(struct node*head) {
    

    
    if(temp==NULL){
        printf("\n\nENTER THE DATA BEFORE SEARCH!!!!\n\n");
    
    }
    else{
        
    printf("Enter the employee number : ");
    int nm;
    scanf("%d",&nm);
    
    
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        
        if(temp->number==nm){
            printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\n",temp->number,temp->name,temp->salary);
        }
        else{
            temp=temp->next ;
        }
    }
    
    selectmenu(head);
}   
    
    
    
}





//creating the menu 
int selectmenu (struct node*head){

    printf("=========EMPLOYEE REGISTRATION SYSTEM=========\n");
    printf("1.Enter Employee Details\n2.Output Employee Details\n3.Search Employee\n4.Exit\n");
    
    printf("Enter the option : ");
    scanf("%d",&op);
    
    switch (op){
        
        case 1:
            createlist();
            selectmenu(head);
            
        case 2:
            
            printlist(head);
            selectmenu(head);
            
        case 3:
            searchemp(head);
            selectmenu(head);
            
        case 4:
            break;
    }
}


int main(struct node*head){


    selectmenu(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int main(struct node*head)` That is not a valid `main` signature.  See [What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function)

Comment: You are not initialising head's next pointer – which will result in error for requested size of 1, on the other hand you later on initialise by NULL but overwrite anyway by all but last element. Simpler: Just set `temp->next` to NULL *after* the loop (last element...).

Comment: `char name;... scanf("%s",&temp->name);` Here `name` is single character, `scanf` will try to write a string to, causes buffer overflow. Your `case` statements are missing `break;` Please work on this a bit more. Your compiler should issue warnings to help you. A good debugger can pick out a lot of bugs. Also, don't try to write the whole program at once. Break it in to smaller parts, first get the input right. Then write a linked list and put it together.

Comment: Do *not* call `selectMenu` recursively – this *will* result in stackoverflow if only the programme runs long enough. Instead write a loop.

Comment: `createList` returns a pointer to the new head – you need to store that somewhere. And you have a memory leak: If you create a new list while one is existing already, you need to first free all the existing nodes before.

Comment: Proper indentation and fewer empty lines make the code more readable!

Comment: `searchemp` ends up in and endless loop *if* you find the employee you are looking for as you won't modify the current pointer any more. And please don't use globals for such purposes, just have another local one.

Comment: @kaylum Oh i see. I will check it out. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks a heap for the help!!! I will try to correct those.

Comment: If *head* is a pointer to a node: node * head, then to pass a pointer to head in C the caller uses | function(...&head) | and the calle uses | function(... node **head) | .

Comment: @rcgldr Thank you so much for the help!!