# C user dynamic input with argv

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, c-strings

So I try to take a user input of unknown max length from the command line. The program to be able to do something like that needs to take a dynamic input of a string (char array maybe?). The outcome should be something like

> ./a.out st1
> your str is ...

the only code I was able to come up with is the following

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    ...
    char str1[];
    str1 = argv[1];
    printf("your...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is interesting what is the meaning of the word Corfu?

Comment: please specify your sample usage of the app and desired results.

Comment: If you execute `a.out your string is the beaches of Corfu` then you want the output: `your string is the beaches of Corfu`, is that correct?

Comment: Vlad I dont know what it has to do with the q but its an island in greek where I study

Comment: Beta yeah I but without spaces

Comment: Are you asking how to use declare arrays in C, or... what? How to copy strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declaration of a block scope array with an empty number of elements:

```
char str1[];
```

is incorrect. Moreover arrays do not have the assignment operator:

```
str1 = argv[1];
```

You could declare a pointer:

```
char *str1;
str1 = argv[1];
printf("your...);
```

Answer (score 0):

C will terminate `argv` with a null pointer, and `argv` [is modifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2108208/2472827), so it's actually very easy to implement `shift` like in [bash scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174566/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-shift-in-shell-scripts). Your basis could look like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *arg;
    if(!argc || !argv[0]) return 0; /* Defensive */
    while(arg = *(++argv))
        printf("do something with %s\n", arg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or you could write a readable loop instead of obscure pointer arithmetic: `for(int i=0; i<argc; i++)
{
  char* arg = argv[i];
  if(arg == NULL) { ... }
}`

Comment: True; not just about style, the way you propose is good if you want the index at which the argument occurs.