# Creating a singly-linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a function to join two structs to create a linked list.

Here, is the code:

```
struct point{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct point *next;
};
void printPoints(struct point *);
void printPoint(struct point *);
struct point * append(struct point *, struct point *);
void main(){
    struct point pt1={1,-1,NULL};
    struct point pt2={2,-2,NULL};
    struct point pt3={3,-3,NULL};
    struct point *start, *end;
    start=end=&pt1;
    end=append(end,&pt2);
    end=append(end,&pt3);
    printPoints(start);
}
void printPoint(struct point *ptr){
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", ptr->x, ptr->y);
}
struct point * append(struct point *end, struct point *newpt){
    end->next=newpt;
    return newpt;
}
void printPoints(struct point *start){
    while(start!=NULL){
        printPoint(start);
        start=start->next;
    }
}
```

Here, the append function's task involves changing the end pointer.

Both the arguments of append function are pointers; in 1st case, 1st argument is `&pt1` and 2nd argument is `&pt2`.

The function makes a copy of the end pointer which has the type `struct point`.
Since `&pt1` is passed then this duplicate end pointer has x component as 1 and y component as -1 and next component as NULL.
Now we change this copy's next component to `newpt` pointer and return the `newpt` pointer.

Back to the main function, the original end pointer now has the value of `&pt2`.

`end->next = newpt;` shouldn't produce any change in the original end pointer in `main` because only the local pointer was changed.

So then why do I get a linked list.

What I get:

```
(1, -1)
(2, -2)
(3, -3)
```

What I think I should get:

```
(1, -1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `end->next = newpt;` shouldn't produce any change in the original end pointer in `main`. Because, only the local pointer was changed

Not quite correct.  It is true that when you call `append`, a *copy* of `end` is made.  However, the `->` operator *dereferences* what that pointer points to.  You would get the same behavior with `(*end).`.  Since the `end` in `main` is the same as the `end` in `append`, they both point to the same thing.  You could have 100 copies of a pointer, all pointing to the same thing.  If you choose one, follow what it points to and change that, then you've changed the same thing that all other 99 pointers point to.  Furthermore, you reassign `end` in `main` by returning `newpt`, so each call to `append` results in an updated `end`.  The output you observe is correct.  Consider the condensed stack frames:

In `main`, at first call to `append`:

```
____main____
|___pt1____| <----+  <-+
|x=1 y=-1  |      |    |
|_next=NULL|      |    |
|___pt2____|      |    |
|___pt3____|      |    |
|__start___|------+    |
|___end____|-----------+      // cell sizes NOT drawn to scale
// start and end both point to pt1
```

Now, on the first call to `append`, the `main` stack frame stays the same, and a new one is created for `append`, where `end` and the address to `pt2` are passed in.

```
|___main____
|___pt1____| <----+  <-+
|_next=NULL|      |    |   // x and y omitted for brevity
|___pt2____|      |    |
|___pt3____|      |    |
|___end____|------+    |
                       |
___append__            |
|___&pt2___|           |
|___end____|-----------+  // also points to pt1 back in main
```

When you use the `->` operator, you *dereference* what that pointer points to.  In this case, `pt1`, so both `end` in `main` and `end` in `append` point to `pt1`.  In `append`, you do

```
end->next = newpt;
```

which is the address of `pt2`. So now your stack frames look like this:

```
|___main____
|___pt1____| <-----------+  <-+
|_next=&pt2|------+      |    |  // x and y omitted for brevity
|          |      |      |    |  // (made pt1 cell bigger just to make the picture clearer, no other reason)
|__________|      |      |    |   
|___pt2____| <----+      |    |
|___pt3____|             |    |
|___end____|-------------+    |
                              |
___append__                   |
|___&pt2___|                  |
|___end____|------------------+  // also points to pt1 back in main
```

Finally, when you return from `append`, you return the address of pt2 and assign it to `end`, so your stack in `main` looks like this before the 2nd call to `append` (again, some cells made larger for picture clarity, this does not suggest anything grew in size):

```
____main____
|___pt1____| <-----------+
|_next=&pt2|---+         |
|          |   |         |
|__________|   |         |
|___pt2____| <-+ <-+     |
|___pt3____|       |     |
|___end____|-------+     |
|___start__|-------------+  // flipped start and end position to make diagram cleaner, they don't really change positions on the stack
```

And you do it all again with your next call to `append`, passing in `end` (now points to `pt2`) and the address of `pt3`.  After all the calls to `append`, `start` points to `pt1`, `pt1->next` points to `pt2`, and `pt2->next` points to `pt3`, just as you see in the output.

One final note, you have an [incorrect function signature for `main`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Illustration of a linked list;Made by me]

As in the illustration `start` still points to `p1` and `end` points to `pt3`.

```c
void main(){
    struct point pt1={1,-1,NULL};
    struct point pt2={2,-2,NULL};
    struct point pt3={3,-3,NULL};
    struct point *start, *end;
    start=end=&pt1;
    end=append(end,&pt2);
    end=append(end,&pt3);
    printPoints(start);
}
```

As in the `main` function, you make `start` and `end` to point at `pt1`.
That's why any changes made to `end` is also seen from `start`.

```c
struct point * append(struct point *end, struct point *newpt){
    end->next=newpt;
    return newpt;
}
```

In the `append` function, `end->next=newpt` which sets the `next` of `end` to `newpt`. In the first case, when `end` points `pt1`, the `next` is set to point at `pt2`. This change in the list is also seen from `start`.

Hence, the output you are getting is correct.

---

## Changing Pointers

When you pass a pointer to a function, the value of the pointer (*that is, the address*) is copied into the function not the value it is pointing at.

So, when you dereference the pointer and change it, the change is also seen from any pointer which contain the same address.
Remember that `p->next` is the same as `(*p).next`.

```c
void change_the_pointer_reference(int* ip)
{
    int i = 1;
    *ip = i;
    printf("%d\n", *ip); // outputs 1
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    change_the_pointer_reference(&i);
    printf("%d\n", i); // outputs 1
}
```

But as the value of the pointer is copied, if you assign to the pointer, this change is only seen locally.

```c
void change_the_pointer(int* ip)
{
    int i = 1;
    ip = &i;
    printf("%d\n", *ip); // outputs 1
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    change_the_pointer(&i);
    printf("%d\n", i); // outputs 0
}
```

Last final note, you have an [incorrect signature of `main`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function)